# npm link [package-name] not creating node_modules in test directory

Tags: typescript, npm

Im building my first npm module however i am having some issues installing my module locally to a test directory. its a typescript project so i'm using `npx tsc` to first create the dist files then I run `npm link` in the same directory as my project's package json. when i run `npm link [test-package]` In the test directory i do not see node_modules get created.
attached is a repo if you would like to see my setup.
https://github.com/BertoGz/test-package.git
Thanks!